# Wordpress Salient theme: getting a full width 2 columns portfolio

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm running Salient 9 theme on wordpress and ​I'm trying to have a full width 2 column portfolio with no luck.

I managed to have a 2 column portfolio using this custom CSS

```
.portfolio-items .col.span_3 {
    width: 47.6% !important;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

but that does not work in full width.
There also seems to be some conflict with my row settings.

If I set the row to "full width content" it is displayed in a very weird fashion, with a narrower background and images spanning out of it.

To display it correctly I have to set the row to "full width background", but I guess that's what is preventing me to have the 2 column portfolio spanning from side do side.

At the moment I've set the page up so that it's totally clear what I mean if you visit it. http://trunkstudio.it/work/​

I'm also attaching a screenshot of the page when I try to set the row to full screen content. [image: wordpress salient - full width content row not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout for those items looks like it's using JS to set the width/position of the images, possible masonry/isotope.

You'd need to override the inline styles, like: (and I shudder to use *important*)

```
.col.span_3.element.one-fourths {
 width: 47.6% !important;
 position: relative !important;
 top: auto !important;
 left: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it a bit differently with

```
.portfolio-items .col.span_4 {
    width: 49.6% !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px;
}
```